# Klipper can't find config files

Tags: raspberry-pi, klipper

I reinstalled Klipper with [kiauh](https://github.com/th33xitus/kiauh) due to other issues I had.

The folder `klipper_config` is still filled with all important config files and all G-code data is there too. But when I start Klipper and enter Mainsail it can't connect to the MCU, can't find G-code files, and has no config files. It is accessing /config and not `klipper_config`. How do I change that?

[image: Screenshot of the Mainsail Config files dialog]